# ` bokeh.models.Range(1,3)`でインスタンス生成できないのは、何故ですか？

Tags: python, bokeh

## 環境

- Python 3.6
- bokeh 0.13.0

## やりたいこと

X軸の表示範囲を指定して、グラフ表示したいです。
以下のコードで、やりたいことは実現できました。

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show,output_notebook

output_notebook()

p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
p.x_range = bokeh.models.Range1d(1,3)
#p.x_range = bokeh.models.Range(1,3) # Error

p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5])

show(p)
```

## 質問

`bokeh.models.Range1d`のドキュメントには、以下のように記載されていました。

> In addition to supplying start and end keyword arguments to the Range1d initializer, you can also instantiate with the convenience syntax:
>   Range(0, 10) # equivalent to Range(start=0, end=10)

https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.Range1d

`Range(0,10)`が使えるそうなので、以下のコードを実行したところエラーが発生しました。

```
p.x_range = bokeh.models.Range(1,3) 
# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

なぜ、エラーが発生したのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問にあるドキュメントは、`Range(start=0, end=10)`を簡便に`Range(0, 10)`とできるとしか書いてありません。要するに`Range`から派生したクラスではそのように書けるということです。

Rangeは、抽象クラスなので実際には使えません。`bokeh.models.Range`のドキュメントには、以下のように記載されています。

> A base class for all range types.
>
> Note
>
> This is an abstract base class used to help organize the hierarchy of Bokeh model types. It is not useful to instantiate on its own.

Comment: RangeとRange1dを見間違えていました。。。。